# How to select unicode text from SQL in codeigniter active record?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

I have a very basic, yet important question that I have been struggling with for over 2 hours now.

**Question**

How to force (N) prefix when selecting from MS-SQL using *CodeIgniter* active record?

This is my code:

**Controller:**

```
$result = $this->users->login($uname, $password);
```

**Model**

```
function login($username = NULL, $password = NULL)
{
    if( !$username || !$password){          
        return FALSE;           
    }

    $this->db->select('CustomerID');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('UsersTbl',array('Username' => $username, 'Password' => $password));

    return $query->row_object();
}
```

---

Now, I have tried putting "N" before the $username in the model function call like:

`array('Username' => 'N\''.$username, 'Password' => $password))`, which constructs the SQL query as: *WHERE Username = 'N'arabicText'*

and tried putting the (N) after the field name, like the '<' or '>' trick in the form:

`array('Username=N' => $username, 'Password' => $password))`which constructs the SQL query as: *WHERE Username =N 'arabicText'* --> And for this to work, the (N) must be directly attached to the text, in the form: ***N'arabicText'***

It all seems to fail...any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer.

**First:**

Change the call in the model to: `$query = $this->db->get_where('UsersTbl',array('Username = N' => $username, 'Password' => $password));`

**Second:**

In codeigniter *System/database/DB_active_rec.php* I've changed the way SQL is contructed in line *427* they add space to the value of "where": `$v = ' '.$this->escape($v)`, Now I had to remove this space so that it becomes: `$v = ''.$this->escape($v)` or just `$v = $this->escape($v)`

Now when I check the $sql it self, it's just how I need it to be: `SELECT CustomerID
FROM UsersTbl
WHERE Username = N'جاد'
AND Password = '123'`

As you can see, the Password field is not affected by the change, because it only applies to the fields with operators =D